# привязка List<double> к datagridview

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте.

Есть статический класс, в котором есть статическое свойство лист с типом double.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно осуществить привязку к компоненту datagridview?

Если брать чисто свойство:

```
public List<double> List { get; set; }
```

В datagridview заполняется таблица, но при попытки считать данные, ругается на отсутствие инициализации. А если так:

```
 private List<double> _nums = new List<double>();

    public List<double> Nums
    {
        get { return _nums; }
        set { _nums = value; }
    }
```

тогда datagridview не заполняется.
В таблице 1 столбик

Comment: Так а `Nums` вы заполняете данными-то?

Comment: Вы пишете «статическое свойство лист с типом double», а в коде оно нестатическое. Кому верить?

Comment: andreycha -  я пытаюсь привязать Nums к datagridview, и в итоге в datagridview никак изменений делать нельзя.
VladD - это я перебирал варианты и в вопросе скопировал не статическое, в принципе, статик не статик, главное чтоб работало)

Comment: @Scarecrow: Не-не, статическое свойство привязывается _не так_, как нестатическое!